# How to rename a file while keeping the middle of the filename in tact

Tags: bash

I'm trying to rename multiple files using a for loop and the mv command.

**FROM:**

```
ATEST1.012345
AZEST2.098765
AZEST3.120565
```

**TO:**

```
atest1.012345_0619
azest2.098765_0619
azest3.120565_0619
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$1

for file in $DIR/ATEST1.??????
do
  mv "$file" "${file%}_$(date +%m%y)"
done

for file in $DIR/AZEST2.??????
do
  mv "$file" "${file%}_$(date +%m%y)"
done

for file in $DIR/AZEST3.??????
do
  mv "$file" "${file%}_$(date +%m%y)"
done
```

The results are: ATEST1.12345_0619, AZEST2.098765_0619, AZEST3.120565_0619.

I'm not sure how to keep the number in the middle and change just the letters and add the _MMYY date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like

```
cd "$DIR" && find . -name "ATEST*" -o -name "AZEST*" | \
while read file;
     do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]])_$(date +%m%y)";
done
```

I recommend using `echo` instead of `mv` for some kind of dry run

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed` you can switch from upper to lower case with `\L`:

```
DIR=$1
for f in $DIR/ATEST1.??????; do
  mv $f $(sed "s/.*/\L&_$(date +%m%y)/" <<< "$f")
done
```

Answer (score 0):

[rename](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) command allows you do bulk file renames.

```
rename  'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/(.*)$/$1_0619/' A*
```

- First (y/A-Z/a-z/) expression replaces uppercase with lowercase
- Second ()  expression appends _0619 to filenames

You could use `-n` flag execute in dry-run mode.

Answer (score 0):

Using tr:

```
for f in $DIR/ATEST1.??????
do
    mv "$f" $(tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' <<< "$f")_$(date +%m%y)
done
```